# A box contains 3, 2, and 4 balls of red, yellow, and green, respectively. What is the number of ways to arrange 6 chosen balls in order?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Question:**
A box contains 3, 2, and 4 balls of red, yellow, and green, respectively. What is the number of ways to arrange 6 chosen balls in order?

**My work:**

For selecting 6 balls from $9$ balls$(3+2+4)$, there are ${}^9C_6 = 84$ ways.

For arranging 6 selected balls in order, we have $84 \times 6! = 68480$ ways.

Is it correct? I think I've not understood the question appropriately. I didn't actually understand what does it mean to find the number of ways to arrange 6 chosen balls "in order"? Which order is being referred to in the question?

Comment: There are the colors to consider, too. You could have one *selection* of, say, $2$ balls of each color. Then each such selection would need to be *arranged* in all possible patterns of colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is asking that order $6$ balls which are from the box. For example, one of the possible orders is $$R-R-G-Y-G-G$$

In this foregoing example, we selected $2$ red (denoted by $R$), $3$ green (denoted by $G$), and $1$ yellow (denoted by $Y$).

- You can also interpret the question such that how many different patterns of length $6$ in line can be made using the balls of the box.

If you try to solve this question using classical approaches ([combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) and [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)), the question becomes cumbersome. Hence, you need a shortcut, the shortcut is [exponential generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) in this example.

Before I write the answer, I want to point out that you cannot make selection by $C(9,6)$ in this example, because the objects are not distict at all. In this case, if you insist on using combination technique, look at combination with repetition, but you will need to use inclusion-exlusion after  [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Anyway, let's turn to our issue. I assume that you read the link and understand the topic, so lets dive into the solution.

- E.G.F for red balls : $$\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} \bigg)$$
- E.G.F for yellow balls : $$\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}\bigg)$$
- E.G.F for green balls : $$\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\bigg)$$

Now , lets find the coefficient of $\frac{x^6}{6!}$ [in the expansion of](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2Bx+%2Bx%5E2+%2F2+%2Bx%5E3+%2F6%29%281%2Bx+%2Bx%5E2+%2F2+%29%281%2Bx+%2Bx%5E2+%2F2+%2Bx%5E3+%2F6%2Bx%5E4+%2F24%29) $$ \bigg[\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} \bigg)\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}\bigg)\bigg(1+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\bigg)\bigg]$$ or find the coefficient of $x^6$ and multiply it by $6!$.

So , $$6! \times \frac{41}{72}=410$$